# How do I import a json property to a dart object when it may or may not exist

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am getting an error message in Flutter `the method map was called on null` when I try to import a JSON file.  The problem is the property may or may not actually exist.

Here is a simplified JSON file to explain the trouble.

```
[
  {"insert":"\n"},
  {"insert":"Some text.","attributes":{"i":true}}
]
```

Here is the code to import it that is failing.

```dart
factory DeltaInsert.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DeltaInsert(
      insert: json['insert'],
      attributes: List<Attribute>.from(
          json["attributes"].map((x) => Attribute.fromJson(x))),
    );
  }
```

How can I get the code to put an empty List instead of a null so the error will stop.  I can not modify the json file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an empty list, maybe use empty square brackets.

```
(json["attributes"]??[]).map((x) => Attribute.fromJson(x))),
```

Comment: Thanks! initializing it as an empty list first did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `?` before calling map. If `json["attributes"]` is Null the whole thing will evaluate to null

```
json["attributes"]?.map((x) => Attribute.fromJson(x))
```

Good article for null safety in Dart: 
“Null-aware Operators in Dart” by Jonathan White https://link.medium.com/BICtG3BKk0

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article!  Checking if attributes exists did help change the error but I still needed to initialize an empty list for the error to completely go away.